# Ubuntu MongoDB: mongos: command not found

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to install a sharded mongo cluster following the official document. [Deploy a Sharded Cluster](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/). And in the document, it says that I will need to use `mongos` instead of `mongod` to start the sharded server. However, I got the `mongos: command not found` error when using the `sudo mongos --config /etc/mongod.conf`. How should I solve this issue?

Comment: Is `mongod` working?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes, mongod is working.

Comment: Then `mongos` should also work, because they are installed together, see [MongoDB Community Edition Packages](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#mongodb-community-edition-packages) unless you only installed `mongodb-org-server`